# Resizing without blur

Tags: resize

I would like to know if there is a way to resize a picture while keeping it's pixelisation

`convert ./TEST.png -resize 723x523 -compose Copy -gravity center -extent 723x523 -quality 92  ./TEST_big.png`

Illustration from 20x20 to 100x100 here: [image](http://static.commentcamarche.net/www.commentcamarche.net/pictures/cRWI1p2Pj8Wjen9SnGBFgGYjHgP4THqLtOlCeChPBmqa9TszfEzyOBVWn4vJcoIG-test-e-s-.png)
`
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one has answered this so I will put what I've done.
I've actually made a Python script who, for each pixel is making a square of n-pixels (10 for example). I'm making the output larger than the picture size I actually want(because I'm only doing squares) with GDAL and then resize it with imageMagick.